# How can I resolve 409 conflict for my website?

Tags: broken-links, http-status-code-409

I am working on website
I am getting 409 error code for conact.php page on this. Although URL is accessible, but ubersuggest and other broken link checking tools returning 409 error code for this single url.

How to fix this issue?

I need help to resolve 409 conflict for my website.